# How do I convert a string text into a class name

Tags: ruby

I have a string as

```
classname = "Text"
```

using this I want to create an object of the Text class

Now when I try doing this

```
classname = classname.constantize
```

I get the Text as a module and not as a class.
Please suggest something.

Thanks and regards

Rohit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use:

```
Object.const_get( class_name )

$ irb 
>> class Person 
>>     def name
>>         "Person instance"
>>     end
>> end
=> nil
>> class_name = "Person"
=> "Person"
>> Object.const_get( class_name ).new.name 
=> "Person instance"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
Object.const_get("String")
```

What "Text" will get turned into depends on your code really.  If it comes back with a module, then Text is a module, because you can't have both a module and a class with the same name.  Maybe there's a Text class in another module you mean to refer to?  It's hard to say more without knowing more about your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
classname = "Text"
Object.const_set(classname, Class.new{def hello;"Hello"; end})

t = Object.const_get(classname).new
puts t.hello # => Hello
```

The trick is explained here: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/anonymous_class_hacks.html
where the author uses it to subclass StandardError.

Comment: what if the class is already defined somewhere else. The user inputs a string and according to that string you have to instantiate the appropriate class. Check the answer of @OscarRyz it gives me the perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Kernel.const_get "Text"
```

For your own defined modules:

```
MyModule.const_get "Text"
```

Answer (score 1):

This would return a new object of class classname:

`eval(classname).new`